# sql many to many relationships, how to find doubles

Tags: sql, duplicates, find, many-to-many

So, I have 3 tables: doctors, organization(where they works) and work places

```
doctors: id, name_s,name_f,name_p,spec  
organization: id, name  
workplaces: id, IdDocs, IdOrg, spec
```

I need to find duplicates error( same full name, one doctor have 2+ specialization in one org, and this spec various)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would all be really helpful.

Comment: You need a `group by org having count(spec)>1`

Answer (score 0):

To find if you have duplicates based on name:

```
SELECT name_s,name_f,name_p
FROM Doctors
GROUP BY name_s,name_f,name_p
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: There is a database of ~ 300 thousand doctors, during synchronization, duplicate errors may appear, and need to find a pair of doctors in all organizations that match by their full name and have different specialties (surgeon, director) in one organization, there are also doctors who work in 2-3 organizations